# How do you sample groups with different sample sizes with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use data.table to speed some calculations on a relatively large dataset. The example below replicates the situation:

```
DT = data.table(a=sample(1:2), b=sample(1:1000,20))
> DT
   a   b
1:  2 440
2:  1   5
3:  2 795
4:  1 138
5:  2 941
6:  1 929
7:  2 759
8:  1 192
9:  2 994
10: 1 176
11: 2 152
12: 1 893
13: 2  28
14: 1 884
15: 2 467
16: 1 761
17: 2 879
18: 1 964
19: 2 802
20: 1 271
```

I want to sample different numbers of replicates groups a==1 and a==2, e.g., n1=5 and n2=3 replicates without replacement, and obtain something like

```
 a   b
1: 2 440
2: 2 879
3: 2 994
4: 2 152
5: 2 879
6: 1 884
7: 1 964
8: 1 929
```

But I cannot seem to be able to get around it with data.table, i.e., I cannot insert the different sample sizes into a data.table commmand. Is there any way to do it? I'm new to data.table and R so any constructive guidance would be greatly apprecieated

Comment: You have more than two groups in `a` in your real data set? Like if these are only two groups, you could just do `DT[a == 1, indx := 3]; DT[a != 1, indx := 5] ; DT[, .SD[sample(.N, indx)], by = a]` or optimize this using `.I` instead of `.SD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to `split` the 'b' column by 'a', pass the 'size' as a vector in `Map` and get the `sample` of 'b' using the corresponding 'size'.  The output is a `list`, which can be converted to a 'data.frame' with 2 columns using `stack`.

```
set.seed(24)
stack(Map(sample, split(DT$b, DT$a), size=c(5,3),MoreArgs=list(replace=FALSE)))
#  values ind
#1    279   1
#2     93   1
#3    665   1
#4    797   1
#5    317   1
#6    542   2
#7    761   2
#8    893   2
```

Or using `data.table` methods, we `melt` the `list` output we got with `Map`.

```
set.seed(24)
DT[, melt(Map(sample, split(b, a), size=c(5,3), MoreArgs=list(replace=FALSE)))]
#  value L1
#1   279  1
#2    93  1
#3   665  1
#4   797  1
#5   317  1
#6   542  2
#7   761  2
#8   893  2
```

Comment: Your first method gives equal sized samples.

Comment: Just a note to be careful if any of the groups has sample size 1 because sample.int comes into play